# Is it possible to somehow save UIActionSheet indexes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I would like to use an ActionSheet for sorting options in an app containing many table views with navigation controllers. My problem is that I cant seem to keep the last selected index on the sheet after poping back one level or quitting the app. The index value defaults back to 0 and I just cant seem to change its initial value. Its possibly something trivial but would really appreciate some help with it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the `UIActionSheet` on subsequent appearances to reflect the current setting?

If so, it may not be the correct UI metaphor to use, since it's just a series of buttons, and there is nothing to distinguish one button from another other than which one cancels an operation or is destructive, and neither of those seem to fit the "sort order" setting you want to keep track of.

What about trying a simple `UITableView` with a `UITableViewCell` that has an `accessoryType` of `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`?  Like in Figure 1-3 [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW4).

Comment: Yes,that is what I'd like to do. The sorting works fine with multiple select sql calls and I was hoping i could somehow keep the last pressed buttonindex but no luck yet. Could you tell what you meant with the accessoryType, I'm not sure how it could help with sorting,but im still a newbie in this so I really might miss something here :).

Comment: I was suggesting that a UIActionSheet may not be the correct UI element to use for what you described, and suggested an alternate that might be better, a UITableView.  Check out the Figure I referenced.

Comment: Oh,that's a good idea.So then a modal tableview that on cell touch sorts the main tableview, sounds good.Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, and it's good form on StackOverflow to either vote a useful answer "up" or check it off as an "accepted answer."  Just saying, since you're new here, no offense taken if you don't :-)

Answer (score 0):

Read some tutorials or books on persistent storage. Core Data or SQLite are available for database needs, or you could store simple values in the `NSUserDefaults`. That should be enough to get you on your way.

Comment: The SQLite database is already made and the sorting works fine,it just resets the buttonindex after quitting and thats what I'd like to solve somehow.